# Como extrair uma palavra de um URL em PHP

Tags: php, string

Nestes exemplos abaixo:

> +bbbbbbb2.virtua.com.br - tirar o virtua
>   +000-74-4-000.paemt702.dsl.brasiltelecom.net.br tirar o brasiltelecom
>   +111.222.22.222.dynamic. adsl.gvt. net.br - tirar o gvt

Já tentei:

```
$texto = "189-72-5-240.paemt702.dsl.brasiltelecom.net.br";  
echo substr($texto,-10);
```

Mas aí ele conta a palavra e fica faltando dependendo do tamanho do host que grava no BD.

Comment: Você quer sempre tirar o nome do domínio, é isso? Tem uma lista fixa de hosts? Tem uma lista de escopo de TLDs, ou seja, é sempre `.net.br`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Se quer o antepenúltimo pedaço do URL:

Esta solução funciona com todos os exemplos dados na pergunta:

```
$pedacos = explode('.',$texto);
echo $pedacos[count($pedacos)-2];
```

Entradas:

```
$texto = "189-72-5-240.paemt702.dsl.brasiltelecom.net.br";  
$texto = "+bbbbbbb2.virtua.com.br";
$texto = "+111.222.22.222.dynamic.adsl.gvt.net.br";
```

Saídas:

```
brasiltelecom
virtua
gvt
```

### O problema de se usar posição fixa:

Se você tiver endereços com sufixos diferentes na lista, posições pré-determinadas podem dar problema, como nos exemplos a seguir:

```
$texto = "bbbbbbb2.virtua.com.br";
$texto = "www.usp.br";  
$texto = "66-97-12-89.datalink.net";
```

Saídas:

```
virtua       Até aqui tudo bem...
www          ... mas neste caso teria que ser "usp"...
66-97-12-89  ... e neste teria que ser datalink !
```

Para resolver o problema segue a ...:

### Solução para endereços com diversos sufixos:

Para resolver o que é sufixo e o que é o nome do domínio propriamente dito, você precisará de um sistema com uma lista de sufixos "oficiais" para consultar o que pode e o que não pode ser retirado do final do URL.

A Mozilla fornece uma lista de sufixos em **https://publicsuffix.org/**.

Esta função resolve bem o problema, se forem aplicados os sufixos de interesse:

```
function NomeDoDominio( $dominio ) {
    // o array precisa estar ordenado dos maiores para os menores
    $sufixos = array( '.com.br', '.net.br', '.org.br', '.com', '.br' );
    foreach( $sufixos as $sufixo ) {
       if( $sufixo == substr( $dominio , -strlen( $sufixo ) ) ) {
          $dominio = substr( $dominio , 0, -strlen( $sufixo ) );
          break;
       }
    }
    return substr( strrchr( '.'.$dominio, '.'), 1);
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/NL76gi)**.

Nota: no caso do Brasil, por exemplo, um endereço pode ser www.jose.silva.nom.br, para complicar mais a situação.

Comment: Eu acho que não precisa ser tão complexo assim.
Existem formas mais simples dele fazer isso, desde q ele tenha um pattern

Comment: De qual das três soluções que eu dei vc está dizendo? (imagino que a 3a, claro.) Eu me baseei no que tem na pergunta, talvez se ele complementar com mais detalhes dê pra otimizar.

Comment: Da ultima, principalmente, seria mais simples ele fazer o explode para um array. depois remover a palavra que ele quer.
assim fica mais genério.

Comment: Eu creio que ele queira extrair, e não remover, mas de fato é uma suposição. Há uma certa ambiguidade no enunciado.

Answer (score 4):

De acordo com a tua pergunta, seja qual for o URL, existe uma consistência que é obter a terceira palavra a cortar do fim:

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────────┐
│ Endereço URL                                    │ Valor a obter │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ +bbbbbbb2.virtua.com.br                         │ virtua        │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ +000-74-4-000.paemt702.dsl.brasiltelecom.net.br │ brasiltelecom │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ +111.222.22.222.dynamic. adsl.gvt. net.br       │ gvt           │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────────┘
```

## Solução

Para esse efeito especifico podes:

```php
$valor = array_reverse(explode(".", $url))[2];
```

1. Estamos a fazer a conversão da *string* `$url` para um *array* partindo a mesma pelo caractere `.` com recurso à função [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).
2. O resultado é enviado para a função [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) que vai inverter o array.
3. Por último limitamos o resultado ao index 2 que corresponde à terceira posição.

## Exemplo

Neste exemplo para os três URLs que também está no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/eael4X), fizemos uma função com o código em cima onde a mesma recebe a *string* e a posição a devolver:

```
<?php
function recolher($url="", $pos=2) {
    return array_reverse(explode(".", $url))[$pos];
}

echo recolher("+bbbbbbb2.virtua.com.br").PHP_EOL;                         // virtua

echo recolher("+000-74-4-000.paemt702.dsl.brasiltelecom.net.br").PHP_EOL; // brasiltelecom

echo recolher("+111.222.22.222.dynamic. adsl.gvt. net.br").PHP_EOL;       // gvt
?>
```

<sup>Para ficar ainda mais flexível, podemos passar o caractere de separação como parâmetro da função.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Bom, vamos lá, essa é uma função genérica para resolver o problema.

**$texto** é o texto da qual vc quer remover a palavra;

**$palavra** é a palavra que será removida;

**$pattern** é o separador que será utilizado (No caso dos exemplos passado, é o '.')

```
function remove($texto, $palavra, $pattern){
    $txt = explode($pattern, $texto); //Transformamos em array
    $id = array_search($palavra, $txt); //Buscamos o índice do array que contém aquela palavra 
    unset($txt[$id]); //Removemos o índice
    $texto = implode($pattern, $txt); //Transformamos o array em uma string novamente.
    return $texto;
}
```

Detalhe que essa função só irá remover a **PRIMEIRA** ocorrência da palavra.

Se você tiver algo como +111.222.22.222.dynamic. **gvt**.adsl.**gvt**. net.br. Ele só remove o primeiro **gvt**

Link para a documentação:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-search.php